# AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'data_samples' on <module '__main__'>

Tags: python

I'm trying to load this dataset, but it just seems to not work.
How can I fix the error?
The code is simple as follows:

```
import pickle      
infile = open('data_set.pkl','rb')   
data = pickle.load(infile)   
infile.close()
```

And the error is:

```
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'data_samples' on <module '__main__'>
```

Comment: The pickle file contains references to a class (or function perhaps) named `data_samples`.  The definition of this needs to be found under the same name for unpicking to be possible.

Comment: Thank you @jasonharper .